# Spring Boot application logs with Docker Desktop

Tags: spring-boot, docker, dockerfile, log4j2

Environment:

> Windows 10
>
> Docker Desktop (2.0)
>
> Running Linux Container of it. on my windows 10 machine.

I would like to store my spring boot app info logs on my C:\log folder.

how to write Volume in Dockerfile for this. So that my spring boot logs gets persisted at C:\log location.

I have created log4j2.json file for this which works perfectly on local ( without container)

Please suggest how to write

Comment: any example? or sample.

Comment: Can you show your docker build command for the spring boot service

Comment: Build Command :  docker build -t dockerdemo .

Run Command: docker run -p 8001:8001 dockerdemo

Answer (score 1):

By default only C:/Users is shared with containers so your dockerfile volume should be something like this /c/Users/youruser/my_volume:/my_mnt

Comment: You mean like this:
FROM openjdk:8
EXPOSE 8089
VOLUME C:/Users/xyz/log:/app/log

Do I need to use same path in log4j2.json for storing my log file? 
What would be the correct value after : /app/log ?
What do you mean by /my_mnt

Comment: The way to write your volume value is VOLUME //C/Users/xyz/log:/app/log

Comment: If you are using docker desktop go to settings-> shared volumes to see the unit letter you are sharing

Comment: sorry above I ommit : VOLUME //C:/Users/xyz/log:/app/log I am used to do it in docker-compose files volumes: - //C:/Users/xyz/log:/app/log

Comment: I have done like this In dockerfile i put Volume /tmp/log , and I am running the container as ##docker run -p 8001:8001 dockerdemo -v //C/Users/myname/log:/tmp/log but it is not showing log file under my host directory

Comment: if you will run the command using console run this just for testing docker run --rm -v c:/Users:/test alpine ls /test this should sync your user folder inside a test folder in alpine image if this not happen and you are not able to see the list of folders of your console you don't have enabled in docker setting any shared drive

Comment: in that case, just got to settings and share c: drive

Comment: i tried the alpine command it gives me below out put >>>>>
ADMINI~1
All Users
Default
Default User
Public
myuser